# Highlight cells between two numbers using conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

How can I apply conditional formatting in Google Sheets that will highlight cells with values between 50 and 100? The built-in options aren't quite cutting it.

Is there a custom formula that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) feature has an **Is between** option that lets you highlight cells with values between 50 and 100 using a specific color.

To create more complex rules, use a  custom formula rule like this:

```
=and(isbetween(A2, 50, 100), iseven(A2))
```